# Shorter way to write existence code like this in Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

My codes looks like this:

```
    _user.role  >= level if _user?
```

I tried the codes below, but found it didn't work

```
    _user?.role  >= level
```

Does anyone have ideas about write shorter codes for this?

Comment: What exactly didn't work with your second piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want in case `_user` is `null`? If you want nothing (`undefined`), then use the first code. If you want `false`, then use second one. Or want another value from the expression?